# Error while unzipping JSON file (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, firefox

in my Node.js application I have a route where I am fetching a big chunk of JSON data from database (Postgres) and sending it in compressed format in a response. I am using `Zlib` module to `gzip` this data. I am setting `Content-Type: application/gzip` and `Content-Encoding: gzip` before sending a response. Now all this set up works well with Chrome and Safari browsers (unzipping data successfully) but for some reason this is not working in Firefox. Request header contains `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`.

In browser(Firefox) console I see following errors

`Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Accept-Encoding` and

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Can anybody please guide me what this issue is and how can I solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will answer my question with what worked for me.

On server side, I changed the way I was compressing the data. I am using `deflate` method of `Zlib` module instead of `gzip`. Also changed the response header with these values.

`Content-Encoding: deflate` and `Content-Type: application/deflate`

I am still not sure why `gzip` does not work (or at least did not work for me) but because of time constraint I am going with `deflate` for now.
Also `gzip` and `deflate` uses same compression algorithm and `deflate` is faster in encoding and decoding. I hope this helps and please correct me if I'm wrong at any place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers,

> For security reasons, some headers can only be controlled by the user agent. These headers include the forbidden header names and forbidden response header names.

[Forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) include "Accept-Encoding".